# What is the difference between ampoule and ampoule électrique?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I want to know how to say “light bulb” in French. What’s the difference between ampoule and ampoule électrique?

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/light-bulb

Comment: The dictionary you post a link to provides both "English to French" and "French to English" translations. You might try reversing the search and then will easily find *ampoule* has (at least) three different meanings in French, only one of which matches "light bulb".

Answer (score 1):

Même si ampoule désigne le plus souvent une ampoule électrique, le terme est plus général. Il peut désigner un récipient ou une formation qui ressemble à ce récipient. Par exemple:

- une ampoule pharmaceutique qui contient une dose de médicament
- une ampoule au pied, bulle de pus sous la peau

La page d'homonymes de Wikipédia donne d'autres exemples d'[ampoules](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampoule).

Answer (score 1):

"*Ampoule*" can mean a lot things, so if you absolutely need to clarify you'll use *ampoule électrique*.

But most of the time, unless the context is extremely ambiguous, "*ampoule*" is fine for "light bulb".